# update indices of a bufferGeometry every frame in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

**I have to update indices of a bufferGeometry in loop function, but only indices which are not assigned can be updated.** If the element of index array be assigned value, it can't be assigned a new value in next time.I search some issues, such as `mesh.geometry.index.needsUpdate = true;`, but it is no effect.

It is my code which create a new Mesh by bufferGeometry.

```
    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

    var pBuff = new ArrayBuffer(MAX_POINTS*3*4);
    var positions = new Float32Array(pBuff);

    var indices = new ArrayBuffer(MAX_POINTS*2*3);
    var iIndices = new Uint16Array(indices);

    positions[0] = 1.0;
    positions[1] = 1.0;
    positions[2] = 1.0;

    positions[3] = 1.0;
    positions[4] = 1.0;
    positions[5] = -1.0;

    positions[6] = -1.0;
    positions[7] = 1.0;
    positions[8] = -1.0;

    positions[9] = -1.0;
    positions[10] = 1.0;
    positions[11] = 1.0;

    positions[12] = 1.0;
    positions[13] = -1.0;
    positions[14] = 1.0;

    positions[15] = 1.0;
    positions[16] = -1.0;
    positions[17] = -1.0;

    positions[18] = -1.0;
    positions[19] = -1.0;
    positions[20] = -1.0;

    positions[21] = -1.0;
    positions[22] = -1.0;
    positions[23] = 1.0;

    iIndices[0] = 0;
    iIndices[1] = 1;
    iIndices[2] = 2;

    iIndices[3] = 2;
    iIndices[4] = 3;
    iIndices[5] = 0;

    geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(positions), 3));
    geometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(iIndices, 1));
    cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'rgb(255, 255, 0)', side: THREE.DoubleSide}));

    scene.add(cube);
```

It is my code which update indices in loop function.

```
var iIndices = cube.geometry.getIndex();
if(change_index){
    iIndices[0] = 0;
    iIndices[1] = 1;
    iIndices[2] = 2;

    iIndices[3] = 2;
    iIndices[4] = 3;
    iIndices[5] = 0;

    change_index = false;
}else{
    iIndices[0] = 4;
    iIndices[1] = 5;
    iIndices[2] = 6;

    iIndices[3] = 6;
    iIndices[4] = 7;
    iIndices[5] = 4;
    change_index = true;
}
cube.geometry.index.needsUpdate = true;

cube.geometry.setDrawRange( 0, 6 );
```

It is the render result.

[image]

only the first assigned index can be keep. such as, indices([0,1,2,2,3,0]) is valid. When I set new value next time, indices([4,5,6,6,7,4]) is invalid.

I search some issues.such as, `cube.geometry.index.needsUpdate = true;` is invalid.Others, `geometry.addAttribute('indices', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(iIndices), 3));` and update `cube.geometry.attributes.indices.array;`. It is invalid.

**How can I update these indices of the bufferGeometry in loop function?**

When I try some method to solve it, I find a low method which have a new problem. How to optimize it.

This is my method.

```
var iIndices = cube.geometry.index.array.subarray(0, 6);
if(change_index){
    iIndices[0] = 0;
    iIndices[1] = 1;
    iIndices[2] = 2;

    iIndices[3] = 6;
    iIndices[4] = 7;
    iIndices[5] = 4;

    change_index = false;
}else{
    iIndices[0] = 4;
    iIndices[1] = 5;
    iIndices[2] = 6;

    iIndices[3] = 2;
    iIndices[4] = 3;
    iIndices[5] = 0;
    change_index = true;
}
cube.geometry.index.needsUpdate = true;
```

This is the result(before).

[result01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAo85.png)

This is the result(after).

[result02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06KXr.png)

The vertices of geometry is invariant, but the indices of geometry(**result01**) is [0,1,2,2,3,0] and the indices of geometry(**result02**) is [4,5,6,6,7,4].When the geometry is rendered, the indices is updated every frame between result01 and result02.

But, The method only support `new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe: false}));`. When `wireframe=true`, the indices of geometry fail to updated.

**How to optimize it When `wireframe=true`?**

Comment: What effect are you trying to accomplish? There is probably a better way than updating the indices each frame.

Comment: What effect I want is that the vertices of geometry is invariant, but the indices of the geometry must be updated every frame(in loop function).

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: What do you want this to _look like_? It seems like you want to make one side of a cube invisible, while making another side visible. Is that correct? Updating the indices is very inefficient compared to other methods, like making separate meshes for each side and setting the `visibility` property as appropriate.

Comment: Thank for your advise. I do some things about "Hidden Point Removal(HPR)".  so I need to update indices every frame. I simplify my problem in my project and ask the problem above.